# How can I view Microsoft Office Custom properties via the GUI?

Tags: ms-word, vsto, ms-office, powerpoint

You can programmatically add or delete custom document properties (also called meta data) to a Microsoft Office application like Word. See this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhxe2d75.aspx) for an example. Now, is there a means to view these added PROGRAMMATICALLY-CREATED custom document properties in Microsoft Office graphical user interface (helps make debugging issues with custom properties easier)?

Comment: Note: I mean programmatically created custom properties; not the Microsoft-created ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. In office 2010 you can find them under:

File, Info. Then on the right side select the "Properties" dropdown and select "advanced properties" It will give you a popup window where the last tab has the custom properties. It is in the windows on this with header "Properties". If you do not see it there, there "could" be the possibility you are not setting it right.

Comment: This does not give me programmatically created custom properties.

Comment: Try adding a custom property using the example for CustomProperties in Help.  If you do that, they do show up as described.

Comment: @Steve Rindsberg. Thanks. I was looking at a file that did not have the property set. Opps.

Comment: @Eddy, thanks. I found it. I also modified your answer a bit.

Comment: "I was looking at a file that did not have the property set."  That'd have an effect on the visibility of the property all right.  ;-)

Comment: As a side note, to get this to work, I had to dirty the document (ActiveDocument.Saved = false) then save it (ActiveDocument.Save()) in order to persist the custom properties AFTER the file is closed and reopened.